# Javascript: Grouping csv data by month instead of day before inserting to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, csv, date, google-apps-script, grouping

I'm very new to Javascript but have recently started modifying scripts to let us pull various csv reports into Google Sheets, using Google Apps Script. The current script we have for this reads the csv file and then inserts all data after the 8th row (since the rows before that just contain info such as when it was generated, report name etc.).

The challenge now is that we need a year-to-date report that is split by month into Sheets (if we split by day we reach the 2 million cell limit). But as the reporting tool in this case doesn't allow to segment by any other date variable than day, we have to do the split within the script. So we would basically have a YTD report sent with ad-level data split by day. This ad-level data is then grouped by month rather than day within the script, before the data is inserted into Sheets. In other words, I want e.g. cost, impression and click data for an ad to be summed for all daily occurrences within one month.

I've looked around intensively the last couple of days but haven't found a working solution for this specific problem yet. I would be super grateful if someone wanted to take a look at this.

**For your reference, please find two scripts below. The first one is the working script we currently have, which just insert the csv data from the 8th row (but no grouping):**

```
 function importData() {
 var sheet_atlas = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet_name');
 sheet_atlas.getRange('A2:V10000').clearContent();
 var sheetName = "sheet_name"

 var threads = GmailApp.search("attachment_name")
 var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
 var newData = [];

  for (var i = 0 ; i < msgs.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < msgs[i].length; j++) {
     var attachments = msgs[i][j].getAttachments();
     var bodyEmail = msgs[0][0].getBody();

     var regExp = new RegExp('a href="(.*?)"', "gi");
     //var regExp = new RegExp('data-saferedirecturl="(.*?)"', "gi"); // "i" is for case insensitive
     var url = regExp.exec(bodyEmail)[1];
     Logger.log(url)
     var decode = new XML('<d>' + url + '</d>');
     var strDecoded = decode.toString()
     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(strDecoded).getContentText();
     var csvdata = Utilities.parseCsv(response)
     var newOrders = []
     //Logger.log(csvdata)
     for (var eachRow in csvdata){
       //for(var col1 in csvdata[8]){
         //if(csvdata[8][col1] == 'Campaign Name'){ var campaignCol = col1 }

         //else if(csvdata[8][col1] == 'Publisher Name'){ var publisherCol = col1 }

         //else if(csvdata[8][col1] == 'Statistics Date'){ var dateCol = col1 }

       //}
         //Logger.log(dateCol)
         //Logger.log(publisherCol)
         //Logger.log(campaignCol)

       if (eachRow>8)
       {
                 var theRow  = [] 
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][0])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][1])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][2])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][3])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][4])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][5])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][6])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][7])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][8])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][9])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][10])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][11])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][12])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][13])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][14])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][15])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][16])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][17])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][18])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][19])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][20])
                 theRow.push(csvdata[eachRow][21])
                 newOrders.push(theRow)
              }
        }
   }

  }
  Logger.log(newOrders)
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(2,1, newOrders.length, newOrders[0].length).setValues(newOrders)

  }
```

**The second one is my current attempt at creating the grouping. So far I've managed to break out the month, but when it comes to the summing part it goes all wrong.**

```
function importData() {
 var sheet_atlas = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet name');
 sheet_atlas.getRange('L2:AA60000').clearContent();
 var sheetName = "sheet name"

 var threads = GmailApp.search("attachment_name")
 var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
 var newData = [];

  for (var i = 0 ; i < msgs.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < msgs[i].length; j++) {
     var attachments = msgs[i][j].getAttachments();
     var bodyEmail = msgs[0][0].getBody();

     var regExp = new RegExp('a href="(.*?)"', "gi");
     var url = regExp.exec(bodyEmail)[1];
     Logger.log(url)
     var decode = new XML('<d>' + url + '</d>');
     var strDecoded = decode.toString()
     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(strDecoded).getContentText();
     var csvdata = Utilities.parseCsv(response)
     var newOrders = []
     //Logger.log(csvdata)
     var currMonth = "";
     var theRow = [];
     var columns = 11;
     var formattedMonth = "";
     for (var eachRow in csvdata){
       //for(var col1 in csvdata[8]){
         //if(csvdata[8][col1] == 'Campaign Name'){ var campaignCol = col1 }

         //else if(csvdata[8][col1] == 'Publisher Name'){ var publisherCol = col1 }

         //else if(csvdata[8][col1] == 'Statistics Date'){ var dateCol = col1 }

       //}
         //Logger.log(dateCol)
         //Logger.log(publisherCol)
         //Logger.log(campaignCol)

       if (eachRow>8)
       {
                var date = csvdata[eachRow][2].split("-")
                var month = date[0]
                if((currMonth != "") && (month.localeCompare(currMonth) != 0)) {
                    theRow[2] = formattedMonth
                    newOrders.push(theRow)
                    theRow = []
                    currMonth = month
                 for (var ci = 0; ci < columns; ci++){
                    // Reset data structure
                    theRow.push("0")
                  }
                }

                formattedMonth = date[0] + "-" + date[2]

                for(var cy = 0; cy < columns; cy++) {
                    if(cy != 2){
                        // Sum the columns
                        theRow[cy] = parseFloat(theRow[cy]) + parseFloat(csvdata[eachRow][cy])
                    }
                }
        }
   }
   // Pushing final row
   Logger.log(formattedMonth)  
   newOrders.push(theRow)

  }
  Logger.log(newOrders)
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(2,12, newOrders.length, newOrders[0].length).setValues(newOrders)

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance and let me know if anything needs to be clarified!

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should aim to reduce your code to the simplest possible to demonstrate your issue—grouping dates by month should be no more than a couple of lines of code whether treated as strings or Date objects. You should also provide sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer as you haven't provided enough information, but some hints on where things might be going wrong.

You really should use semi-colons to end expressions, whoever left you this code to maintain needs to be reminded of their obligations to others.

One issue in your code is that *currMonth* is an empty string:

```
var currMonth = "";

...

   if (eachRow > 8)
   {
        var date = csvdata[eachRow][2].split("-")
        var month = date[0]

        // This expression must always return false since currMonth == ""
        if((currMonth != "") && (month.localeCompare(currMonth) != 0)) {
                theRow[2] = formattedMonth
                newOrders.push(theRow)
                theRow = []

                // this statement expression will never be executed,
                // so currMonth remains an empty string
                currMonth = month
             for (var ci = 0; ci < columns; ci++){
                // Reset data structure
                theRow.push("0")
              }
            }
```

Also looking at:

```
for (var eachRow in csvdata){

    if (eachRow>8)
```

presumably *eachRow* is a string, comparing it to a number using `>` will always return false if `Number(eachRow)` does not return a number (e.g. it will evaluate correctly if *eachRow* is a string like "12" or "6" but not a string like "2017-08-28").

You need to supply a sample for *csvdata* and the output you expect from processing it.